# How to speed up directory search

Tags: c#

Writing a find largest method that takes a file directory as input. Looping through directory files and searching for the largest after 100 + rnd. But I have a lot of files so it takes awhile. What is the best way to speed it up? Not really sure the best solution. Possibly a type of thread pool? Here is what I have. Also, please assume that the line is already validated before being converted to int. Thanks.

Edit: There is an int on each line of the file. Not just one per file.
Edit 2: Operation is currently about 900ms, ideally need to drop that by like 400%.

```
public static int FindLargest()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Dir");

    List<int> values = new List<int>();

    foreach (var fileName in files)
    {
        var file = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        foreach(var line in file)
        {
            int product = PerformAddition(Convert.ToInt32(line));

            if(product >= 100) values.Add(product);
        }
    }

    int largest = 0;
    foreach(int value in values)
    {
        if(value > largest) largest = value;
    }

    return largest;
}

public static int PerformAddition(int value)
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    return value + rnd.Next(0, 100);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this article would be of use: [Microsoft - How To Iterate File Directories With The Parallel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-iterate-file-directories-with-the-parallel-class). TheGeneral's answer is likely the real answer you're looking for but I'll leave that Microsoft resource here in the event you're interested.

Comment: @TylerRoper nope, there is a new int on each line of the file. I need to read by line.

Comment: @TylerRoper are the files, just ints + new line? nothing else

Comment: yep, just int + new line.

Comment: Dunno what if you'll see a performance boost or not.. but you are allocating a new `Random` each time `PerformAddition` is called.  This is bad for two reasons.  1)  The allocation of the object per line in each file is going to be costly.  Remedy it by making a class-level field:  `private static Random _random = new Random();`   2) allocating a new random within the same millisecond will yield a non-random result (will yield the same result as the last Random that was allocated in that ms).  The static field alleviates this issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Race your horses!

So the premise is to test the original version again some other solutions

The tests were carried out over 100 files and run 10 times. The scale is how many lines of ints in a file

Lastly, i removed the random so i could verify the results

## Results

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .NET Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 10 times (averaged)

Scale : 100
Name         |   Average |  Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Mine4        |  2.323 ms | 2.191 ms | 0.13 |  2,241,488 | Yes
johnPlusMine |  2.676 ms | 2.064 ms | 0.33 |  6,117,891 | Yes
john         |  3.124 ms | 2.723 ms | 0.27 |  8,914,485 | Yes
Original     | 10.004 ms | 9.146 ms | 0.71 | 34,025,586 | Base
Mine3        | 10.279 ms | 7.012 ms | 2.45 | 31,679,870 | Yes


Scale : 1,000
Name         |   Average |   Fastest | StDv |      Cycles | Pass
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine4        |  4.037 ms |  3.363 ms | 0.45 |   2,566,176 | Yes
johnPlusMine |  4.606 ms |  3.040 ms | 1.61 |  10,893,833 | Yes
john         |  8.307 ms |  7.118 ms | 0.70 |  18,582,130 | Yes
Mine3        | 11.023 ms |  9.498 ms | 1.61 |  37,394,603 | Yes
Original     | 33.316 ms | 23.887 ms | 8.29 | 108,467,775 | Base


Scale : 10,000
Name         |    Average |    Fastest | StDv |      Cycles | Pass
---------------------------------------------------------------------
johnPlusMine |  12.643 ms |  11.908 ms | 0.62 |  21,985,225 | Yes
Mine4        |  12.655 ms |  11.074 ms | 1.00 |   2,482,408 | Yes
Mine3        |  38.223 ms |  37.495 ms | 0.83 | 130,130,301 | Yes
john         |  53.337 ms |  47.496 ms | 3.79 | 126,151,357 | Yes
Original     | 194.628 ms | 185.462 ms | 9.20 | 660,359,390 | Base


Scale : 100,000
Name         |      Average |      Fastest |  StDv |        Cycles | Pass
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
johnPlusMine |   195.336 ms |   179.742 ms | 12.09 |   166,869,434 | Yes
Mine4        |   209.209 ms |   180.388 ms | 22.50 |     3,220,582 | Yes
Mine3        |   331.211 ms |   313.332 ms | 19.35 | 1,097,353,237 | Yes
john         |   489.939 ms |   455.913 ms | 26.35 |   910,277,113 | Yes
Original     | 2,877.904 ms | 2,845.898 ms | 31.42 | 9,584,556,134 | Base
```

## Mine 3

Basically this is an `unsafe` `fixed` version using pointers and manual parsing

```
protected override unsafe int InternalRun()
{
   var largest = int.MinValue;

   var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ints");
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
      var content = File.ReadAllText(file);

      fixed (char* pContent = content)
      {
         var len = pContent + content.Length;
         var current = 0;

         for (var p = pContent; p < len; p++)
         {
            if (*p >= 48)
            {
               current = current * 10 + *p - 48;
            }
            else
            {
               if (current > largest)
               {
                  largest = current;
               }
               current = 0;
               p++;
            }
         }

         current = 0;
         if (current > largest)
         {
            largest = current;
         }
      }
   }

   return largest;
}
```

## Mine4

This uses `ActionBlocks` and `unsafe`

```
private static volatile int _max = int.MinValue;

private static readonly object _sync = new object();

public static async Task<int> DoWorkLoads(string[] files)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<string>((Action<string>)MyMethodAsync, options);

   foreach (var file in files)
   {
      block.Post(file);
   }

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;
   return _max;
}

unsafe public static void MyMethodAsync(string fileName)
{

      var largest = int.MinValue;
      var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

      fixed (char* pContent = content)
      {
         var len = pContent + content.Length;
         var current = 0;

         for (var p = pContent; p < len; p++)
         {
            if (*p >= 48)
            {
               current = current * 10 + *p - 48;
            }
            else
            {
               if (current > largest)
               {
                  largest = current;
               }
               current = 0;
               p++;
            }
         }

         current = 0;
         if (current > largest)
         {
            largest = current;
         }
      }

      lock (_sync)
      {
         if (largest > _max)
         {
            _max = largest;
         }
      }

}

protected override int InternalRun()
{
   _max = 0;
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ints");
   var result = DoWorkLoads(files)
      .Result;
   return result;
}
```

## JohnPlusMine

```
private static object _sync = new object();

private static int _max;

public static unsafe void MyMethodAsync(string fileName)
{
   var largest = int.MinValue;
   var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

   fixed (char* pContent = content)
   {
      var len = pContent + content.Length;
      var current = 0;

      for (var p = pContent; p < len; p++)
      {
         if (*p >= 48)
         {
            current = current * 10 + *p - 48;
         }
         else
         {
            if (current > largest)
            {
               largest = current;
            }
            current = 0;
            p++;
         }
      }

      current = 0;
      if (current > largest)
      {
         largest = current;
      }
   }

   lock (_sync)
   {
      if (largest > _max)
      {
         _max = largest;
      }
   }
}

protected override int InternalRun()
{
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ints");

   Parallel.ForEach(files, MyMethodAsync);

   return _max;
}
```

## Further notes

My other attempts were using `async` `await` and action blocks, the idea was to let IO bound tasks be IO bound tasks, however the results didn't fair out that well. In the end i could probably get more speed if i used `Parallel.ForEarch` however i run out of energy.

Anyway, if you were to use the unsafe versions, you need to set the project to use unsafe code in the properties, also it has no error checking, so if you feed in garbage it will output garbage. Also, you might want to fiddle with the MaxDegreeOfParallelism for maximum affect.

Honestly though, you are probably better going with johns answer, its more straight forward unless you were trying to squeeze the last bit of performance out

## Original Post

Do this

```
// var content = File.ReadAllLines(file);
```

Basically, you are reading the contents of the file for no apparent reason

Comment: I need to read by line, not the whole file. There is a new int on each line.

Comment: @bobtoss `var content = File.ReadAllLines(file);` you are never using the content of the file , im guessing you want this `foreach(var line in content)` however that will not speed you up

Comment: @bobtoss hold your horses big fella, i am getting you an update

Comment: how's it going bro?

Comment: they will be 10kb max.

Comment: You know, this is why I love programming. Even something simple like this has so many different approaches :)

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it like this:

```
public static int FindLargest()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Dir");

    int largest = 0;
    Object lockObject = new object();

    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file))
        {
            int product = PerformAddition(Convert.ToInt32(line));
            if (product < 100)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (product > largest)
            {
                lock(lockObject)
                {
                    if (product >  largest)
                    {
                        largest = product;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return largest;
}
```

It runs through each file in parallel, and enumerates the lines instead of loading them all into memory. Since you only want the largest value, I've avoided storing the values in memory opting for keeping track of the largest as we go.

For each line of the file we:

1. Skip out if the value is < 100
2. Check if product > largest
3. Lock to gain exclusive access to the code block inside (so only one thread can update `largest` at a time.
4. Check again if product > largest (another thread could have updated the value while we were waiting for a lock).

Finally, we return the largest value.

Since the `Random` class is, by default, initialized using a seed from the current system time, so you might get duplicate random values. I've written some code which will create a new `Random` instance per thread  (since my method is multi-threaded. If you go with a non multi-threaded approach, you can just use one instance of `Random`):

```
public static class ThreadSafeRandom
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Random _random = null;

    public static Random Random
    {
        get
        {
            if (_random == null)
            {
                int seed = 0;
                lock (_lockObject)
                {
                    seed = rnd.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
                }
                _random = new Random(seed);
            }
            return _random;
        }
    }
}

public static int PerformAddition(int value)
{
    return value + ThreadSafeRandom.Random.Next(0, 100);
}
```

In my testing on my system (SSD, i7 4770k) I can consistently process 100 files with a combined total size of ~75 megabytes in under 750 milliseconds. In terms of rows, it's about 7500 rows per millisecond.

Comment: i was hoping someone else played, benchmarks comming!

Comment: @TheGeneral I'll await the results then :)

Comment: @TheGeneral I just realised a huge problem with OP's random addition method :)

Comment: Yeah indeed, i have fixed that in my tests

Comment: Updated, i think if we mixed both our approaches it would be slightly faster again

Comment: Im voting yours for the win, i mean he is less likely to get him self into trouble

Comment: @TheGeneral Well, you have my upvote since your answer is also good, and you did the extra legwork to do the comparisons :)